# Protractor 3.2.2 .debugInfoEnabled=false;

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The newer version of protractor (3.2.2) documentation says that you don't need to set `window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO"` in order to test angular applications with `.debugInfoEnabled=false`.

I'm using protractor 3.2.2 now and still not able to run my test WITHOUT hacking it with 
`browser.executeScript('window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO!"');`

I can't seem to get it working. Did you guys have any luck with it?

Thank you!